# jquery slide using css3 transitions with multiple use

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, css-transitions

My jquery slide works very well, but I need to be able to use it more than once within a page.

- How can I have use for 2 slide in the same page?
- how can I remove the next and prev buttons if i got only 6 elements? like this below?
- if ($('.wrap').length <= 1) {
        return;
    }

  worksGallery: function () {
            $('ul.og-grid > li').each(function (i) {
            if (i % 6 == 0) {
                $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0, 6).wrapAll('
  ');
            }
            });
  ```
        $('ul.og-grid .wrap:gt(0)').removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeout');

        updateNav = function () {
            $('#eventi .prev').toggle($('.wrap:first').hasClass('fadeout'));
            $('#eventi .next').toggle($('.wrap:last').hasClass('fadeout'));
        }

        $('#eventi .prev').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var idx = $('.wrap.fadeIn').index() - 1;
            $('.wrap.fadeIn').addClass('fadeout').removeClass('fadeIn').css("transition",1/(idx+1)+"s").css("transform", "translateX(" + 660 * idx + "px)").index() - 1;
            $('.wrap').eq(idx).addClass('fadeIn').removeClass('fadeout').css("transition",1/(idx+1)+"s").css("transform", "translateX(" + -660 * idx + "px)");
            updateNav();
        });

        $('#eventi .next').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var idx = $('.wrap.fadeIn').index() + 1;
            $('.wrap.fadeIn').addClass('fadeout').removeClass('fadeIn').css("transition",1/(idx+1)+"s").css("transform", "translateX(" + -660 * idx + "px)").index() + 1;
            $('.wrap').eq(idx).addClass('fadeIn').removeClass('fadeout').css("transition",1/(idx+1)+"s").css("transform", "translateX(" + -660 * idx + "px)");
            updateNav();
        });

        updateNav();

        if ($('.wrap').length <= 1) {
            return;
        }

      },
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/yGaj8/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to play with hide in jquery .

Comment: thanks I more focused to make this slide working in a multiple way. any suggestions?

Comment: would u be able to help?